# What is air pressure on Marzocchi forks?

Tags: maintenance

I have changed oil in a set of Marzocchi Drop Off forks with 110mm travel. I can’t find the recommended air pressure on Marzocchi website. There is a spring on one side. I think they are 2004 but not certain, forks are black coloured throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Air pressures in Marzocchi Bomber All Mountain forks are between 2.0 & 4.5 bar.  The range is suggested and based on rider weight.  Obviously, desired sag is a factor in your choice of pressure as well.   I've copied the chart from a 2006 Bomber AM maintenance guide.  I can't find the web link at the moment.  The use of commas and periods is confusing to me, but this is exactly how it's written in the book.  The commas are like a decimal point in the U.S.

(User weight ) Air pressure

(kg.) (lb.) bar | psi

(55 - 70)(121 - 154) 2,00 - 2,75 | 2.900,00 - 3.987,50
(70 - 80) (154 - 176) 2,40 - 3,10 | 3.480,00 - 4.495,00
(80 - 95) (176 - 209) 2,90 - 3,80| 4.205,00 - 5.510,00
(95 - 110+) (209 - 242) 3,60 - 4,50| 5.220,00 - 6.525,00

The maintenance guide I have deals with 110, 130 & 150 mm of travel AM forks and there is only one air chart for all three.

Comment: Many thanks Jeff, You helped more than Marzocchi did.

Comment: @jnjock61Lol. In all fairness, Marzocchi is the source.  Though their website is dearth except for the latest stuff. Any early archive is not readily navigated to.